# Retrieve specific value from MySQL DB in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working with a MySQL sign up/registration system. If the user and pass are correct and has permission 0, he will log in as guest; if the user and pass are correct and user has permission 1, he will log in as administrator. If the user is guest, I want to open Form1, if he is admin, I will open Form 2. At this point my program reads / writes to the MySQL DB. How can I read a specific value (permission) and write conditionals depending on the result?

Auth :

```
        private bool validate_login(string user, string pass)
    {
        db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from miembros where usuario=@user and contraseña=@pass";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (login.Read())
        {

            connect.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            connect.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just access the data reader

```
if (login.Read())
        {
            x = login["FieldName"];
            connect.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            connect.Close();
            return false;
        }
```

a general advice to you when you are going to use MySQL with C#, it's better to use a framework like NHibernate that will help you with data access and date formats and many other things.

Comment: Where x is a string, int or bool?

Comment: x is an object and you can cast the result or you can use 
login.GetInt32(0); if you are want to retrieve integervalue